# O meu if else não funciona no Console.ReadKey, então tava fazendo um programinha ele tá executando mas ele "pula" os comandos dentro do if else

Tags: c#, .net, console

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace projeto
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dados a = new Dados();

            Console.Write("Entre com o numero da conta: ");
            a.Nconta = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.Write("Entre com o nome: ");
            a.Nome = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine();
            
            // O erro começa aqui em baixo

            Console.Write("Haverá um deposito inicial (s/n)? :  ");
            var deposito = Console.ReadKey().ToString();

            if (deposito == "N")
            {
                double depositado = 0;
            }
            else if (deposito == "S")
            {
                Console.Write("Entre com o valor depositado: ");
                double depositado = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Tem vários erros nesse código. Vou corrigir alguns, mas não todos, principalmente o objeto da conta que deveria ter construtor, métodos que fazem certas operações em vez de acessar os dados de forma direta. E não tratei erros de forma adequada, só não deixar acontecer.

Dei nome melhor para o que é o objeto que está querendo tratar. E usando o tipo correto para lidar com valor monetário.

Eu testo se o dado digitado faz sentido e só aceito ele quando está ok. Do jeito que estava quebrava a aplicação por uma digitação errada.

Dei nomes mais significativos para todas variáveis.

Quando eu pergunto sim ou não eu peço um texto normal, até porque deixar só uma tecla definir o que vai fazer pode não ser uma boa UI. Na verdade eu nem perguntaria isso, eu pedira o valor e aceito o 0, mas não tirei isso para mostrar como corrige o valor.

`ReadKey()` não faz o que espera, ele não retorna um texto ou um número que faça sentido como texto, ele retorna o código da tecla, e não um código de um caractere.

E não pode declarar uma variável condicionalmente.

```
using static System.Console;
using System;

namespace Projeto {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main() {
            Conta conta = new Conta();
            Write("Entre com o numero da conta: ");
            if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var numero)) return;
            conta.Numero = numero;
            WriteLine();
            Write("Entre com o nome: ");
            conta.Nome = ReadLine();
            WriteLine();
            Write("Haverá um deposito inicial (s/n)? :  ");
            var temDeposito = ReadLine();
            var valor = 0M;
            if (temDeposito.Equals("S", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) {
                Write("Entre com o valor depositado: ");
                if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out valor)) return;
            }
            conta.Saldo = valor;
        }
    }
    
    public class Conta {
        public int Numero { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public decimal Saldo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/r7c6yH). E [no **repl.it**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/81SLn3). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Console/ReadKeyLine.cs).

Comment: Nossa cara vc é um anjo! muito obrigado!

Comment: @Apectocio veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado aqui.